# Parse.User.current()._sessionToken returns undefined

Tags: parse-platform

I have been using `Parse.User.current()._sessionToken` for a long time on Parse JavaScript SDK v `1.4.2` and I then use this `sessionToken` in my REST API calls.

It seems that they have removed the method `Parse.User.current()._sessionToken` however my question is what has it been replaced with? I cannot find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see an API at [`getSessionToken`](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.User.html#methods_getSessionToken) that you might be able to use.

So why not try `Parse.User.current().getSessionToken()`?

Comment: I get this `Parse.User.getSessionToken is not a function` error

Comment: did you append the parenths at the end, too?